# Как закрасить всю область под кривой линией в линейном графике matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Имеется простой линейный график (фото ниже).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно закрасить всё под кривой? Как бы получатся такие закрашенные "горы".

**Вот код:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.array(["01.02.2002", "01.02.2003", "01.02.2004", "01.02.2005", "01.02.2006", "01.03.2006", "01.02.2007",
              "01.02.2008", "01.02.2009", "01.02.2010", "01.02.2011", "01.02.2012", "01.02.2013", "01.02.2014"])

y = np.array([25, 71, 61, 33, 11, 3, 1,
              25, 31, 41, 33, 11, 25, 18])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглить не пробовали или рецепты какие по `matplotlib` почитать? :)

```
plt.fill_between(x, y, np.zeros_like(y), color='cyan')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я гуглил уже, нашёл этот метод "fill_between", но не понял что именно нужно передавать в аргументах.

Comment: Ну там вроде по описанию функции понятно: `x, y, y1`, т.е. на каких `x` и между какими `y` нужно закрасить. В вашем случае - между вашим `y` и нулевой линией